# Laravel 5.3 chain paginate after filter

Tags: php, laravel

```
$posts = Post::all()->filter(function($item) use (&$pYear){
    return Persian::jDate(...) == $pYear;
})->sortByDesc('id')->paginate(5);
```

When I chain paginate(5), I get this error "Method paginate does not exist.", How can I paginate my result, please help, thank you.

Comment: did you integrate paginate in your view?

Comment: @DiegoCespedes, {!! $posts->links() !!} ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved it by creating a custom paginator of my collection, Maybe this is not the best way, I couldn't find a shorter solution, anyway my code works fine now.

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

protected $perPage = 5;

$posts = Post::get()->filter(function($item) use (&$pYear){
    return Persian::jDate(...) == $pYear;
})->sortByDesc('id');

//this code simulates: ->paginate(5)
$posts = new LengthAwarePaginator(
         $posts->slice((LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage() *
         $this->perPage)-$this->perPage,
         $this->perPage)->all(), count($posts),
         $this->perPage, null, ['path' => '']);
```

Comment: this is either an outdated method or just doesn't work. Method Algolia\ScoutExtended\Builder::slice does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `all()`

```
$posts = Post::filter(function($item) use (&$pYear){
    return Persian::jDate('Y', strtotime($item->created_at),'','Asia/Tehran','en') == $pYear;
})->sortByDesc('id')->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::filter()

Comment: You might better make it work with `->where` closure instead of `filter`

Comment: I need a code similar to this but this does not work! `$posts = Post::where(Persian::jDate('Y', strtotime('created_at'),'','Asia/Tehran','en'), $pYear);`